# How do airflow sql_sensors interpret skipped tasks from separate DAGs?

Tags: short-circuiting, airflow

I am looking to utilize the ShortCircuit operator in DAG 1, so that it skips the DAG run if data is not available on a given day.

I have a DAG 2 which triggers DAG 1 and checks the status of individual DAG 1 tasks along the way, using sql_sensors. These sensors prevent DAG 2 from continuing, until they recognize that the associated task that it is checking in DAG 1 has succeeded.

My question is, if DAG 1 is short circuited on a given day, and all downstream tasks are set to 'skipped', how would the sql_sensor on DAG 2 interpret the skipped tasks? Would it consider them as 'success' and move on to downstream tasks?

Comment: Could you elaborate how are you using [`SqlSensor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/cdec3012542b45d23a05f62d69110944ba542e2a/airflow/sensors/sql_sensor.py) to check status of tasks? (are you using them to poll Airflow's `SQLAlchemy` *backend meta-db*?). If you were using `ExternalTaskSensor` (the conventional way of *sensing* other `task`s), it provides [`allowed_states` param](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b61225a8850b20be17842c2428b91d873584c4da/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.py#L45) to configure the behaviour you want

Comment: @y2k-shubham yes we are using the sqlsensors to see if a row was written to an audit table so unfortunately I don't think I can use the allowed states with ExternalTaskSensor.